# In 3D space, how to project a point into x, y and z?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say we have a point in a 3D space and we need to project the x component onto the x, y and z components onto the x-axis, y-axis and z-axis respectively with respect to the eigenvectors.
How can we do that?
The input:
a point in 3D.
the Origin <0,0,0>
an eigenvectors $e_x, e_y$ and $e_z$
the output:
a projected point onto x, y, and y-axis.
does multiply the point by the eigenvectors (basis matrix) will solve this problem?

Concrete example:
Here is a point P and the bisis vectors
$
P=<0.348499, 2.137199, -0.438428>
e_x = <0.944485, -0.244727, 0.219221>
e_y = <0.275648, 0.953309, -0.12337>
e_z = <-0.178793, 0.176948, 0.967844>
$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually already done if you're just projecting onto the standard coordinate axes:

$$P_X = <x,0,0>$$

$$P_Y = <0,y,0>$$

$$P_Z = <0,0,z>$$

Just take the point's coordinates and put them into three new points, with zeroes elsewhere.

However, if you are projecting onto an arbitrary *unit* vector, $e_i$, then the answer is to project the position vector of the point onto $\hat{e}_i$ as follows:

$$P_e = (P\cdot\hat{e}_i)\hat{e}_i$$

Where I've abused notation slightly an treated $P$ as its own position vector, which I'll do unashamedly.

Comment: You are right! that will work for the standard coordinate i.e $e_x=<1,0,0> e_y=<0,1,0> e_z=<0,0,1>$. However, if we have different base then this solution will not work.

Comment: Then I think you should re-word your question.  Most of the time when we say "the x axis" we mean "the canonical x axis, $<1,0,0>$.  I'll edit my answer to be more general

Comment: $P_e$ is a point that is projected onto $e_i$.

Comment: $P_e$ is a point that is projected onto $e_i$.What about the other vectors? I men each component of the new $P$ should represent the projection onto the respective axis. How can I address that without dealing with each component separately? I believe matrices can do that.

Comment: The magnitude of each new $P_e$ is what you're looking for.  You compute all 3 projections, one for each axis.  Let's call them $P_1$, $P_2$, and $P_3$.  Then these each have magnitudes $p1$, $p2$,$p3$.  The new vector would be given as $p1\hat{e}_1 + p2 \hat{e}_2 + p3\hat{e}_3$

Comment: Great! I accept your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The orthogonal projection of a vector $\mathbf v$ onto *any* other nonzero vector $\mathbf w$ is ${\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf w\over\mathbf w\cdot\mathbf w}\mathbf w$. If $\mathbf w$ happens to be a unit vector, then of course the denominator is equal to $1$.

The coordinates of a point are the ratios of the lengths of its projections onto the basis vectors and the lengths of the basis vectors. Those projections might not be orthogonal, but if the coordinate system is orthonormal then the point’s coordinates in that system are exactly the lengths of its orthogonal projections onto the basis vectors.